# Android Room implementation with background threading handling queries

Tags: java, android

I am recently trying to learn Android and I am very new to backend knowledge e.g. threading and stuff. I got Room figured out and try to integrate it with front end component. So, I am not worried how front end adapting the data I want it to present. I have the problem trying to design and implement the integration in a clean way using thread and trying to implement threading since I am new to it.

Here is my code.

Database.class

```
@Database(entities = {Groups.class, Member.class}, version = 1, exportSchema 
= false)
public abstract class DatabaseConfig extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    private static DatabaseConfig INSTANCE;
    public abstract GroupDao groupDao();
    public abstract MemberDao memberDao();

    public static DatabaseConfig getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (DatabaseConfig.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = 
                        Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            DatabaseConfig.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .addCallback(DatabaseCallBack)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback DatabaseCallBack =
        new RoomDatabase.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void onOpen (@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db){
                super.onOpen(db);
            }
        };
}
```

GroupRepo.class

```
public class GroupRepo {
    private final GroupDao groupDao;
    //ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public GroupRepo (Context context){
        DatabaseConfig db = DatabaseConfig.getDatabase(context);
        groupDao = db.groupDao();
    }

    public List<Groups> getAllGroups(){
        /*
          So my idea is to have some sort of threading implement from here
          and use executor.run() to run my query and capture data
         */
    }
}
```

Groups.class

```
@Dao
public interface GroupDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from groups")
    List<Groups> getAllGroups();

    @Query("Select * from groups where groups.id = :groupsId")
    GroupAllMembers getAllMember(int groupsId);

    @Insert
    void insert(Groups... groups);

    @Delete
    void delete(Groups groups);
}
```

I am not going to post my Entity class since my intention is not about that. I am fairly new to background threads. Please help and ideally provide some example to help me understand.

Comment: I believe Room, if I remember rightly, throws an exception (probably IO?) if you try IO operations on the main thread anyway, so you have to do it off the main UI thread anyway? Use the `Executor` you have commented out to do the work for by posting `Runnable`s.  Your Singleton, if only accessed by one `Thread` does not need to be synchronised.  If you don't understand Threading its best a bit about it first, rather than try to apply it blindly, or use the Rx Room library extensions, which offer threading very easily.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to handle this: if you are doing the query on the database for UI view, I'd recommend your Day return LiveData> and then put that inside of a viewmodel. All of this is covered in Android docs.

If you are doing it in a service or don't want to interact with UI simply do this:

```
Thread(Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do your stuff here with Room
    }
}).start()
```